# type 'List<Serializable>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MyManagedObject>'

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I'm using `aqueduct` and I'm receving the error

```
'List<Serializable>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MyManagedObject>' of 'list' #0 _TypeError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:89:51)
```

but I don't know what is? I was running my code ok and just I receive this error that I can't solve, I google a lot but I can't find a solution.
This is my 'entrypoint'

```
@override
Controller get entryPoint {
  final router = Router();
  router
        .route('${apiBaseUrl}/objects')
        .link(() => ObjectController(context));
}
```

and this is my post method:

```
@Operation.post()
Future<Response> createMyObject(@Bind.body() List<MyManagedObject> list) async {
  ...
  return Response.ok("ok");
}
```

I think that can be a error of lib but I just can't know.

Comment: did you read the serialization docs? https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/request_and_response/#serializable-objects It's possible they don't support `List<T>` but I am not sure... anyway, looks like your list takes `MyObject` and the error says `MyManagedObject`?

Comment: thanks Renato, I change the real classe for 'MyObject' for a better abstraction. I'm reading your link, but I used with 'List' after a upgrade then broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a breaking change in Dart 2.1.1 that caused an issue with binding lists. It has been fixed in Aqueduct 3.2 (released today 3/7).